# If $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $a,b \in G$ such that $a = b$, is $aN = bN$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

If $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $a,b \in G$ such that $a = b$, is $aN = bN$?

My proof:

By definition, $aN = \{an : n \in N\}$. But $a = b$, so $aN = \{bn : n \in N\} = bN$.

Is this true?

Comment: There is no difference between $aN$ and $aN$, for your case that $a=b$, as there is no difference between $a$ and $a$. So the question is empty - sorry to say this.

Comment: Yes, it's trivially true. It has nothing to do with cosets - it doesn't even matter what $aN$ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

One way to describe this is that equality is a *right compatible* relation. This means that for all $g,x,y\in G$, we have

$$x=y\implies xg=yg.$$

This can be seen in your calculations: $a=b$ implies $\color{red}{an=bn}$; indeed:

$$\begin{align}
aN&=\{\color{red}{an}\mid n\in N\}\\
&=\{\color{red}{bn}\mid n\in N\}\\
&=bN.
\end{align}$$